# Rest Service implemented using PHP Slim Framework return Ajax error function, although the Ajax method works and the data was saved?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, slim

I implemented a Rest Service using the PHP framework named `Slim`, the service works fine, because i also tested in `SoapUI` and works without problems. The Service is very simple, it just saves the data into txt file. Although when i consume the service via javascript using a Ajax post method it works, and the data is saved in the file, but the **error function is executed instead the success function**. Any ideas, whats going wrong?

**Service-> PHP SLIM FRAMEWORK**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app=new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/gravar_documento', 'gravar_doc');

function gravar_doc(){
    $request=Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data=$request->getbody();
    $dados=json_decode($data,true);
    file_put_contents('test.txt',  $dados["test"]);

    $app=Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $response = $app->response();
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $response->status(200);
    $response->body(json_encode((object) array('success'=>true)));
}
$app->run();
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "Service_url->hidden for safety",
        data: JSON.stringify( { test: 1, val: 2} ),
        success: function(data){
            alert("IN");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: what does data output when it is within the error callback??

Comment: Right now is not doing anything yet

Comment: try setting the Accept header to 'application/json'. One possibility I see is that the ajax call did not say, I can eat json but you gave a json anyways. I guess that could have errored

Comment: I already try to set on ajax method "datatype : "application/json" and contentType: "json" and the error continues, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally can get the solution. I want to thank to everybody who tried to help me, the simple solution is to add in the first line of PHP code the following:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

And it will work, at least works for me.

Comment: Caution against this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: Thanks, we need to be careful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

well you still need to see the return data, thats why you should console.log the data back. the callback data is not the same scope as the data that you stringify. If you output the data out prior to your alert, it will tell you what is your API response to your request.

Comment: I already excludes the input parameter "data" of success and error functions. I just want alert the success and the failure. But in this case, when the success occurs the ajax method alerts failure wrong. The status code returned on AJAX is 0. Thanks

Comment: @john what you don't understand is that we are trying to get more information on the debug of your ajax. The debug happens in two places: the data returned and the debug console. Maybe your API is throwing 500 when the ajax is called, maybe the ajax itself is tossing a 500 without you know. All those information helps us debug your code.

Comment: The problem is that I can't debug the ajax with the console.log, i just can do alert.

Comment: @John then open up firebug or google dev console and check if it at least doesn't return 500. Another way to check is to have POSTMAN do the ajax call because POSTMAN acts like your API client, which will mimic your ajax call

Comment: But i install the http live headers, and you rigth the server (WS) return the code 500

Comment: What can i do to change this situation? Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i had a problem in my server, and momentaneously the response was 500, but now the response given is 200 OK. But Ajax still return the error function.